# Format with Prettier on save doesn't work in WebStorm 2022.2.2

Tags: webstorm, prettier

I installed everything like in official tutorial https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/prettier.html#ws_prettier_reformat_code and it doesn't work on save, although the checkbox is set.

What can I do to make it work?

[image: prettier configuration in WebStorm]

- Prettier version: 2.7.1
- WebStorm version: 2022.2.2

Comment: Does it work on Reformat Code?

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't working for me because the selected version of my node interpreter was too old.

To change it, open settings => search node and select a more recent node interpreter (for me go from 10 to 16) and restart Webstorm.

[image]

Comment: It won't work if you don't restart Webstorm!

Comment: Cool. For further readers, do not forget to restart Webstorm

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure you have correct file extensions included, for instance if you are working with Vue add vue to the list:

```
{**/*,*}.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,vue}
```

Answer (score 1):

Must be [WEB-57086](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-57086/Prettier-option-Run-for-files-doesnt-work-for-glob-pattern-with-directory-name-in-the-path-eg-src), Prettier plugin doesn't work if you have a directory name in a glob pattern.

Try changing the **Run for files:** back to default value, `{**/*,*}.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,scc,scss,sass}`

Answer (score 0):

You should include prettier in dev dependencies in the package.json as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your prettier by explicitly running it from the terminal:  `prettier . --write` and check the output for errors.

If there are any errors, try fixing them, restart the IDE, and try again.

I had the same issue and this is how I found out I was supposed to name the prettier config file `prettier.config.mjs` instead of `prettier.config.js` to solve it.

I hope this helps.